# use VIPER architecture with Class or Struct in swift?

Tags: swift, struct, viper-architecture

When we want write project with VIPER architecture, we should use Struct or Class in defining `Presenter` or `Interactor` or ...

Because we should use `Class` for `View` ( because of inherit from `UIViewcontroller` ), so if we write `Presenter` with Strcut, what will happen for performane or memory leak or ...?

```
class HomeView: UIViewController {

    var presenter: HomeViewPresenterProtocol?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ...
    }
}


struct HomePresenter {

    var view: HomeViewProtocol?

    ...
}
```

we should use `weak var presenter: HomeViewPresenterProtocol?` in view or without weak?

what will happen if we use struct in VIPER?

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of VIPER architecture, it’s recommended to use struct by default and use a class if you need the specific features of a class such as the inheritance you mentioned.
Also, it's a bad practice to use a struct if it contains any reference type.

In your case, I recommend you use a class because VIPER Interpreter and Presenter are usually stateful and contain reference types.

To know more when to use struct or a class, I recommend you to check the following article:
https://medium.com/commencis/stop-using-structs-e1be9a86376f

Comment: you said "it’s recommended to use struct by default". but after that you said it's bad practice. so?

Comment: i think we should use class for `View`, so as result of your word we should also use class for `Presenter` becasue of bad practice....

all viper architect related to `Presenter`, so all of viper will be class. yes?